# Kendo UI Angular DatePicker moves scroll position

Tags: angular, datepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

I have used the basic usage example for the Kendo UI Angular DatePicker.

However, when the DatePicker is clicked it annoyingly scrolls to a different position to open the DatePicker if there is a scroll bar.

Html:

```
<kendo-datepicker ></kendo-datepicker>
```

The package.json looks like:

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^2.2.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.50.0",
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IntlModule,
    DateInputsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas why it would change the scroll position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described issue is a known bug caused by an immediate popup content focusing that DatePicker performs. It is addressed in the latest (at the time of writing) Kendo Popup for Angular. To install it, just run the following command:

```
npm install @progress/kendo-angular-popup@2.2.0
```

More details about the issue can be found in the related Github thread:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1459

Answer (score 0):

its a bug on Kendo Datepicker.

I've the same problem. But i've found a workaround.

The scrolling happens on `toggleFocus()` function in the `DatePickerComponent`.

To fix this you have only to import the `DatePickerComponent` in your component.

```
import { DatePickerComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs";
```

and add this at the end of your component this code.

```
(DatePickerComponent as any).prototype.toggleFocus = function() {};
```

Should looks like this.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DatePickerComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-your-component",
  templateUrl: "./yourComponent.component.html",
})
export class YourComponent {}

(DatePickerComponent as any).prototype.toggleFocus = function() {};
```